# maven build projects in sequence automatically in my case

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have three maven projects(Java) **A**, **B**, **C**. They are “parallel” projects. No parent-child relationship.

Their relationship however is:

- Project **B** depends on **A**.
- Project **C** depends on **B**.

What I want to achieve is under project **C**, when I run `mvn clean install`, it could automatically find
the above relationship, and build in a sequence of **A—> B —> C** ?

How can I achieve it in project **C**'s pom.xml?

(I know I can achieve it by creating an "parent" project and define A, B, C as modules. But I am seeking for a way that **avoid** creating "parent" project)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without creating an aggregator project that sits above them in your directory structure and defines each of them as module.

Note that a *parent* module is not the same as an aggregator. The sub modules do not need to refer to the aggregator's POM at all.